# Is it possible to snap to the edge of a stroke in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, snapping

If I have a line segment with a stroke on it in Illustrator, is there any way to snap to the edges of that stroke instead of the middle? I know I could convert the stroke to a path, but I don't want to do that because I may want to change the stroke width later on. I've included a screenshot below to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot]

Is this possible? And, if not, are there any good workarounds?

Comment: I believe this was added to the new version. But even if it wasnt you can allways expand a copy of the stroke. (This leaves the stroke intact)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "expand a copy of the stroke," @joojaa?

Comment: Ctrl+c, ctrl+f, expand, snap, delete/hide expanded shape

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, like joojaa suggested, is to duplicate and expand (i.e. convert the stroke to a path). Then you group the two so you can transform them together.

If the path is closed you can play with the 'align stroke' parameter (stroke panel) to have it be internal or external.

Comment: Why store the expanded one you can allways remake it?